# How to tell Webpack 5 with splitChunks and MiniCssExtractPlugin to create a separate vendors.css from node_modules using only one entry?

Tags: webpack

In my **Webpack@5.52.0** project, my goal is to always have `index.js`, `index.css`, `vendors.js`, **`vendors.css`** as the result of each build, but with using **only one entry** (<- important!):

```js
    entry: {
      index: path.resolve(conf.SRC_ROOT, "assets/index.js")
    },
```

My entry `index.js` has all the imports like:

```js
require("./index") // <- my scripts
require("./vendors") // <- vendor scripts imports from node_modules
import "./index.scss"; // <- my sytles
import "./vendors.scss"; // <- vendor styles imports from node_modules
```

So I'm trying to configure code splitting with `optimization.splitChunks` to let Webpack generate these results/bundles for me:

- `index.js` = my scripts
- `index.css` = my styles
- `vendors.js` = all JS stuff coming from `node_modules`
- `vendors.css` = all CSS stuff coming from `node_modules`

With the following config (part) Webpack generates only `index.js`, `vendors.js`, and `index.css` which contains **all my CSS**, so splitting to `vendors.css` is missing... I've tried a lot of suggestions found on Google but none of them worked.

```js
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'all',
          }
        }
      },
```

Excuse me to not pasteing here my huge `webpack.config.js` but I'm almost certain that the solution hides in a proper `splitChunks` configuration. FYI: my loaders for styles are: `sass-loader` -> `resolve-url-loader` -> `postcss-loader` -> `css-loader` -> `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`.

*Please note: Currently, I'm using it with 2 entries like this below, and it's working well without any `splitChunks` config, but I would like to solve the problem I'm asking above.*

```js
    // entry: {
    //   vendors: path.resolve(conf.SRC_ROOT, "assets/vendors.js"),
    //   index: {
    //     import: path.resolve(conf.SRC_ROOT, "assets/index.js"),
    //     dependOn: "vendors"
    //   },
    // },
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you solved this issue? I have in the same situation.

Comment: @Mork No, I gave it up and being in a different business since then.